# AS removeEventListener before or after An object been removed

Tags: actionscript-3

Quick question; should I use `removeChild()` or `removeEventListener()` first?

Also, if I set an object to `null`, do I still need to remove event listeners from that object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Remove event listeners before removeChild."

Whether doing the other way will throw an error or not, totally depends on the event you are listening to & the objects you are trying to access after the event fires.

But it always a good practice to remove event listeners as fast as you can.

For example : If you require the click of a button once & you seem to disable the button after click, It doesn't make sense to keep the listener running.

---

And Yes you do need to manually remove all event listeners. But you can also use weak event listeners:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked, false, 0, true);
```

Which hints the garbage collector to remove the listener when object is set to null.

Comment: You may want to mention in your second example that you're referring to the `useWeakReference` argument - there's a lack of context at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

> Should I remove all the eventListener before removeChild, or removeChild before eventListener.

These tasks are unrelated, so it doesn't matter. That said, there are some events which are triggered by removing a child, so if you're relying on `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`, then you'll want to remove the event listener AFTER.

> If I set an object to NULL, do I still need to removeEventListener?

Yes.